# Predict the encoded content of cookies

Tags: cookies, client

Excuse in advance as this is a silly question but who knows, maybe there is a workaround this problem...
Say, I access any website which makes use of cookies to store session data, user id or anything else. The cookies sent by the server to the client machine are encoded so that they could be interpreted only by the server. Obviously, it is only possible to decode the cookie on server's end. 
My question is: can we predict the type of data that has been encoded and stored in the cookie? (e.g. by looking at http requests and responses, execution of javascript). Is there even (remote) possibility of being able to decode it on client's end?

I'm currently working on a project that would show the flow of information passed between client and the server. I need look for a way to extract the details relevant to the user that would be contained in cookies, cache, flash cookies, server http header response, etc. By relevant details I mean  PII or non-PII like age, gender.

Comment: Obviously, if the cookie content is securely encrypted, then no, you can't decode it (at least, not without the key).

Comment: I think you'll find very few sites will actually store PII in the cookies, its too verbose and degrades perf, instead the cookies will just contain keys pointing to PII on the server.